# AB Testing for Magento

Tags: magento

What software can be used for A/B Testing for Magento?

I have experimented with Visual Website Optimizer (http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/) in the past, but it only allows you to make minor changes such as changing images, and text, but doesn't allow you to make structural changes to the page's layout.

I was wondering which software would be good for allowing layout changes, but also if it is especially built to integrate with Magento, that would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you need,

If you want complete layout change so you can do another store view with different theme etc..

If you need some changes in some places there is alot of tool that allow you to AB Testing

Last one i have used and was satisfied was http://www.optimizely.com

There is alot more with different options but in the end they all nearly the same

http://unbounce.com/

http://www.whichmvt.com/

http://www.maxymiser.com/

Comment: Thanks for that. These software allow you to completely change the layout though?

Comment: You can change the whole layout css images etc.. but again most of them is based on javascript so its not actual layout changes :)